# R partial data.frame replication

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having data.frame like this:

```
h   d   m   v1      v2      v3      v4
0   4   0   0.8556  0.8556  0.8554  0.8556
0   4   0   0.8568  0.8568  0.8566  0.8568
1   4   0   0.8602  0.8602  0.8602  0.8602
1   4   0   0.8568  0.8568  0.8528  0.8530
2   4   0   0.8566  0.8568  0.8566  0.8568
```

more generally it can be represented as:

```
h1  d1  m1  v11  v12  v13  v14
h2  d2  m2  v21  v22  v23  v24
h3  d3  m3  v31  v32  v33  v34
h4  d4  m4  v41  v42  v43  v44
h5  d5  m5  v51  v52  v53  v54
```

I'm looking for the way to transform it as following - having parameter *recordsPerRow* (equals **3** for example) the output would be:

```
h1  d1  m1  v11  v12  v13  v14  v21  v22  v23  v24  v31  v32  v33  v34 
h2  d2  m2  v21  v22  v23  v24  v31  v32  v33  v34  v41  v42  v43  v44
h3  d3  m3  v31  v32  v33  v34  v41  v42  v43  v44  v51  v52  v53  v54
```

So it tooks the *i* row as it is and appends only *v_* values from the next *i < i + recordsPerRow* rows to it.

I created a function which does the job but while it's based on for loops it's pretty slow (data.frame with around 300000 records takes several minutes):

```
  rows <- nrow(data)
  cols <- ncol(data)

  rowLength <- 3 + 4 * recordsPerRow
  resultedRows <- rows - recordsPerRow + 1
  resultLength <- resultedRows
  result <- numeric(resultedRows * rowLength)

  for (i in 1:resultLength) {
    for(j in 1:recordsPerRow) {
      if (j == 1) {
        startIndex <- 1 + (i - 1) * rowLength
        endIndex <- startIndex + 7 - 1 # + 7 -> row length; - 1 -> end is inclusive
        result[startIndex:endIndex] <- as.numeric(data[i + j - 1,2:cols])

      } else {
        startIndex <- lastIndex
        endIndex <- startIndex + 4 - 1 # + 4 -> row length; - 1 -> end is inclusive
        result[startIndex:endIndex] <- as.numeric(data[i + j - 1,5:cols])
      }
      lastIndex <- endIndex + 1
    }

  }
  result <- as.data.frame(matrix(result, ncol = rowLength, byrow = T))
```

I wonder if there is more efficient solution?

Comment: What's the logic behind leaving out the last two rows of the first 3 columns?

Comment: @mtoto If I understand your question correctly, last two rows where omitted assuming it's the end of the data.frame. There are not enough rows to create 4th output row because it should look like `h4 d4 m4 v41 v42 ... v61 v62 v63 v64` and there is now row nr 6 with values like `v61 v62`. So the length of output data.frame will be *length of input data.frame - recordsPerRow + 1*

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 3

do.call(cbind, lapply(1:(nrow(df)-n+1), function(i) df[i:(i+n-1), 4:7]))
#   V4  V5  V6  V7  V4  V5  V6  V7  V4  V5  V6  V7
#1 v11 v12 v13 v14 v21 v22 v23 v24 v31 v32 v33 v34
#2 v21 v22 v23 v24 v31 v32 v33 v34 v41 v42 v43 v44
#3 v31 v32 v33 v34 v41 v42 v43 v44 v51 v52 v53 v54
```

Comment: Well, it works a little different. It always creates `n` rows and `nrow(df) - n + 1` columns. So if i have df with 10 rows and n=3 it will create df with 3 rows and 32 (8 * 4) columns while I would like to have df with 8 rows and 12 (3 * 4) columns.

Comment: @f1ames if you understand the above, should be obvious how to change it